# Windows 8 application to allow two users per single PC

Tags: windows, windows-8, virtualization

Currently I'm running VMWare Workstation and I'm able to have me and one other user play League of Legends using separate peripherals. The graphics are a bit choppy when huge fights happen (due to large amount of graphics) and I'm wondering if there's a solution.

I do not need answers saying to buy another computer (I've gotten a lot of these) as I do not have the room for another computer, I'm very very poor, and I already have it working I just want to increase performance.

My specs are as follows:

http://ca.pcpartpicker.com/b/CF3

Can anyone recommend any software that would be better at doing the job better then VM?

Just for clarity it needs to:

1. Use my second screen
2. Be fast enough to play league of legends without getting choppy fps
3. Be free/cheap
4. Be able to use separate peripherals connected to my pc